# Java runtime.exec() out of android avd

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I have a problem in running Unix shell commands during android testing: during the execurion, the environment is the virtual device, so i can run commmands inside the device but i'd like to execute normals shell commands, "outside" the virtual device. There is a way to execute them?

Comment: What is in/outside of what here?

Answer (score 0):

Android Debug Bridge - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html - although I have no idea what "in" or "out" of the device means to you.

Comment: sorry, i try to explain. executing android testing java code, i need execute some shell commands during the test. to do that i use runtime.exec("cmd") method, but while running test,the filesystem where i can do operations (ls, rm, mkdir..) is the device filesystem, not the computer filesystem. i'd like to run shell commands in the computer filesystem. Hope to been clear.